# difference between completableFuture.completeExceptionally() to throwing an exception

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

When I use `completeExceptionally` I cannot prevent from the thread running it to keep running the code after it.
if I throw an exception after the complete exceptionally then the .get() will catch that exception and not the exception i threw in the `completeExceptionally`

```
if(doProcessException){
        log.error("before Completeexceptionally called");
        cf.completeExceptionally(new StepException("Dummy exception thrown in doProcess",new IOException("dummy IOExcetion in dummy step"), this.getStepName()));
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
logs.error("After Completeexceptionally called, why am i running?);
```

if I `completeExceptionally` I don't want the code , log.error in my snippet, to run...

I want the thread that ran that logic with the `CompletableFuture` to stop...

If I run the code above, the empty runtime exception gets caught and not the detailed exception I put in the `completeExceptionally()`

If I even remove the `completeExceptionally()` I end up in the same catch on my .get()

If so, what is the purpose of `completableFuture.exceptionally(() -> {})` if I have to handle the .get() exceptions anyway?

What ever I wrote in the `completeExceptionally` I can put in the catch section of my `completableFuture.get()`, and then I just throw an exception in the runnable, and thus stop any farther progress of that thread.

I'm probably using it incorrectly...

EDIT:
Ill give more details as requested in the comments

My scenario is kinda complicated so ill try to simplify it

I have 2 layers, an infrastructue layer that creates a chain of completableFutures with the `.thenComposeAsync()` method.

after the chain is created i use `.get(timeout)` to block my infra code and give the entire chain timeout to finish the job.

this `.get()` forces me to try catch like so

```
try {
        finalEnrichmentResponse = completableFuture.get(enrichmentTimeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        endResult = finalEnrichmentResponse.getData();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        enrichmentException(enrichmentResponse.getData(), finalEnrichmentResponse, e, "Step chain threw InterruptedException");
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        enrichmentException(enrichmentResponse.getData(), finalEnrichmentResponse, e, "Step chain threw ExecutionException...");
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        enrichmentException(enrichmentResponse.getData(), finalEnrichmentResponse, e, "Step chain exceeded the configured timeout: " + enrichmentTimeoutMs + "ms");
    }
```

to my understanding, those catches are if the comletableFuture threw an exception. and doesnt have an `.exceptionally()` method which is fine by me for safety.

now my issue starts in my logic layer, there i used another completable future for each "step" as i called it in the chain.

the steps in my chain are working synchronically.

so basically i call the method of the step which returns a completableFuture and perform a `get()` like so

```
stepResponse = doProcessCf.get();

                } catch (EntityStoppedException e) {
                   //specific handling
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   //specific handling
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   //specific handling
                }
```

here i dont give a timeout since if the actual logic is timeing out its already calculate by the timeout chain...

Im aware this architecture might be bad but this was my first try with completable futures.

since i dont have an `completableFuture.exceptionally` in the logic layer, if to logic programmer `completeEexceptionally()` then the catch handles it.

this might be my problem? and i need to  add an `.exceptionally(() ->{})` to that completableFuture?

anyhow, the thing is that if the comepletableFuture i get from the step, performs somewhere in the code `completeExceptionally()`, then the rest of the code he wrote after that is still running.

so maybe the solution is just to tell the step programmer to manage his code in a way that if he decides to `completeExceptionally()` he cant have any code run after it? a single point of return esque instruction.

for simplicity we can assume that the chain only has 1 step.

I thought it can be done in a more elegant way.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The whole point of a CompletableFuture is that it executes in a different thread (provided by an Executor).  Throwing a RuntimeException in this thread has no effect on the other thread.  If you want to stop the background task, [give the CompletableFuture a custom ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.Executor)) and call its [shutdownNow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()) method.

Comment: the code there is the other thread that runs, and only there i know if i need to shut it down.. since the compleExceptionally doesnt do it for the thread it runs on. the code will run till the end there, and in the thread that created the completableFuture he will execute the .exceptionally(() ->{}) i provided. so even if i shut it down in the exceptionally section, still the code will continue faster then i will be able to shut it down ( assuming it happens concurently). am i wrong?

Comment: If you could provide a [mre] of your scenario it would make it easier for someone to properly answer your question. But in general, completing a `CompletableFuture` exceptionally allows all dependent stages to react to the failure as appropriate; if you throw an exception without completing the future then the dependent stages will never be notified of the failure.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)—it appears you are using completeExceptionally to do something it can’t possibly do.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want an asynchronous task to cancel itself?  Do you want a thread which is outside of the CompletableFuture to halt the CompletableFuture?  Do you want to halt a CompletableFuture and then immediately terminate the method which is waiting for it?

Comment: I edited the question to contain much more information, and by doing so i think i mightve found the solution, but still i would love to hear your opinion!